# is NSManagedObjectContextDidSave or save thread safe?

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data

I am having a structure of parent/child relationship context.

The parent is main context and the child is private concurrent context.

when the child does some changes and do `save`. The main context (object) receives the notification and do `NSManagedObjectContextDidSave`.

The problem is that I am wondering if this action is thread safe? because even it's wrapped in is't own context/thread (inside `mainContext.performBlock`), the other thread - child concurrent thread for example, can do the fetch. Will it corrupt the data when these 2 actions happen at exact time?

Answer (score 1):

performBlock : synchronously performs the block on the context's queue. and is not thread safe in case of saving multiple records.

performBlockAndWait:  synchronously performs the block on the context's queue. May safely be called subroutine.